# ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a performance issue where the application cannot execute a DB query when a particular page is accessed and the page fails to load. The stack trace for the error is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:246)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getCallSynthData(Unknown Source)
at com.avaya.ces.gui.rmi.CallSynthDataServiceRmiClient.getCallSynthData(CallSynthDataServiceRmiClient.java:107)
... 98 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:393)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:185)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:214)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:914)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:244)
... 103 more
```

This issue is observed when the DB size is growing rapidly (approx. 3GB a day). Any suggestions on how to prevent this or fix this would be really appreciated.

Hardware specs where this server is running:
CPU : Dual Core – 2.3GHz, Mem: 4GB , Disk : 242 G, OS : RHEL 6.4 64 bit

Postgres pgdata size: 21839 MB

Comment: I think you need to show the original exception from the other side of the RMI method invocation. This one doesn't provide any useful information because you (or the framework in use) has not enabled RMI classloading, so the exception details cannot be printed. If you can't do that, take a look at the PostgreSQL server error logs instead, see if there's anything informative there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual exception is `ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`, and it is caused by not deploying the PSQL JAR file at the client.